# Opendiff does not start anymore

Tags: xcode, versions, filemerge, opendiff

Today I tried to use opendiff on my MacBook Pro and I got this error.

```
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode folder is set. Run xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path> to set the path to the Xcode folder.
Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error.
```

Do you have any idea why it suddenly start happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 20):

That is because with 4.3 `/Developer/` moved to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`

The proper setting for the new path is:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/
```

I am still unsure why I stopped working though.

Comment: Thanks.  This fixed the issue for me as well.  Not sure why these answers were downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/
```

worked for me

-- I use Versions with FileMerge and started seeing the same error code immediately after upgrading to OSX 10.7.3

Comment: Did not work for me (xCode 4.3.1), but this worked fine:               sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/